# Can you hold 2 student visas at once?

Tags: usa, visa, australia, study

For example if you hold an F1 visa and you want to study abroad (Australia for example) for one semester ?

Comment: It seems that even if you take a leave for more than 5 months, as long as you're registered and endorsed by the school's international office (e.g. research), you should be fine and will not need a new I20. See https://www.ufic.ufl.edu/iss/currentF1studentsLOA.html

Answer (score 2):

Based on the information [here](https://www.ice.gov/sevis/travel), it looks like the answer is yes if you stay 5 months or less. The US doesn't care if you have an Australian visa.

However, you need to get the approval of the designated school official (DSO) who will endorse your I-20 for travel, and make sure your SEVIS record is up-to-date.

You also need to make sure that your original entry visa is still valid, or obtain a new one to re-enter the US. Simply being in F-1 status is not enough.

Your passport (depending on its country of origin) should also be valid for at least 6 months when you re-enter the US.